# Laravel many-to-many relation required unexpected table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two tables with many-to-many relation

```
class Psychologist extends Model 
{

public function specs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Spec');
}

public function methods()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Method');
}

}
```

Its working fine on saving first relation 'App\Models\Spec' `$psy->specs()->attach(explode(',',$data['spec']));` with table name 'psychologist_spec' and get exception of incorrect table 'method_psychologist'
instead of 'psychologist_method'

```
public function save(Request $req)
    {
        $data = $req->all();
        $psy = Psychologist::create($data);
        $psy->specs()->attach(explode(',',$data['spec']));
        $psy->methods()->attach(explode(',',$data['methods'])); 
    }
```

I know that i can explicitly indicate table name like

```
 public function methods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Method', 'psychologist_method');
    }
```

but cant understand why it working in the first case and doesnt in the second

Comment: define `$table` in Method model like this [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names)

Comment: Very simple, Laravel orders the model names for the pivot table name by alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer